# Rigorously proving something using little oh notation

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

First, let me introduce the notation.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces. For $f: U \subset_{\circ} X \to Y$, such that $0 \in U$, we say that $f(x) = o(x)$ if $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\|f(x)\|}{\|x\|} = 0$.

Consider the following example:

> For $X,Y,Z$ normed vector spaces, $x_0 \in X$, and $f: U \subset_{\circ} X \to Y$ and $A: U \to L(Y,Z)=\{L: Y \to Z: \text{linear and continuous}\}$, if $f$ and $A$ are differentiable at $x_0$ then so is the map $Af: x \in U \mapsto (Af)(x) = A(x) [f(x)] \in Z$.

Let us proceed:

$$(Af)(x_0 + h) - (Af)(x_0) = A(x_0+h)f(x_0 +h) -A(x_0 +h)f(x_0) + A(x_0 + h)f(x_0) - A(x_0)f(x_0) = A(x_0 + h)[f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)] +[A(x_0 +h)- A(x_0)]f(x_0) \\ = A(x_0 +h)[ \color{red}{Df(x_0) h + o(h)}] + [\color{red} {DA(x_0)h +o(h)}]f(x_0)$$

Now, how to **rigorously** deal with the last expression in order to get:

$$A(x_0)[Df(x_0)h] + DA(x_0)h[f(x_0)] + o(h)$$

and conclude?

I can argue with epsilons and deltas, but I am quite sick of them. On the other hand, I do want to work this out rigorously, so I would like to know how this is done.

Added later:

From where I am reading, the author (Bruce Driver) writes:

$$A(x_0+h)f(x_0+h) = (A(x_0) + DA(x_0)h + o(h))(f(x_0) + Df(x_0) h + o(h)) \\ = A(x_0) f(x_0) + A(x_0) Df(x_0)h + [DA(x_0)h] f(x_0) + o(h)$$

Which seems to imply that he somehow "distributed" and omitted the $\epsilon(h)$ terms (i.e. terms $\to 0$ as $h\to 0$), then grouped together the $o(h)$ terms in a single $o(h)$. I might be wrong though, and even if I am thinking right, I don't know why he is allowed to do that given that there are two kinds of $o(h)$ involved (one related to the operator norm and the other to vector norm). Can someone shed some light on this?

It is completely fine if you exclusively address in your answer any of the two questions (they are practically equivalent, I just added the latter for some context). Also, if you just think that you can offer some valuable remark or piece of information, please feel free to post it as an answer as well (with or without proof).

Comment: Taylor? $A(x_0+h)=A(x_0)+DA(x_0)h+o(h)$.

Comment: @CedricT yes I can add that, the point is: how to "multiply out" things rigorously in order to get to that last expression.

Comment: Well any term containing $h^2$ is clearly $o(h)$ (just use the definition). Also a term like const*$o(h)$ is also $o(h)$. Not sure if this answers your question. I can write it out in an official answer if you want.

Comment: @CedricT I am self-learning these things, so I am not familiar with common kinds of manipulations used in such situations. Thus, I am looking for an answer which explains each major step using the definition of $o(h)$ or explicitly uses some established properties of $o(h)$. For instance, $DA(x_0)h$ is a map $Y \to Z$, so how to interpret the $o(h)$ next to it or must it be dealt with in a different way than the $o(h)$ next to the $Df(x_0)h$? I hope that I am making myself clear.

Comment: $$h\cdot h=o(h)\quad h\cdot o(h)=o(h)\quad o(h)\cdot o(h)=o(h)$$

Comment: @Did what are $h\cdot h$, $h \cdot o(h)$ and $o(h) \cdot o(h)$ supposed to mean? Specifically, what is $h \cdot h$?

Comment: Sorry? What is "what" supposed to mean?

Comment: @Did sorry, I edited my comment to make my question more clear.

Comment: ?? $h\cdot h=h^2$.

Comment: @Did please note that I am not working in $R$ or $R^n$

Comment: @BanachManifold Ouch!, I now understand my last comments were quite bad and there indeed seems to be more to it. About how to interpret $DA(x_0)h (o(h))$, this means: the operator $DA(x_0)h$ applied to any vector $x(h)$ whose norm depends on $h$ in such a way that: $\lim_{||h||\rightarrow 0} \frac{||x(h)||}{||h||}=0$.

Comment: As for the rest of the proof I think you will have to use things like : $||Df(x_0)h||\leq M~||h||$ for some constant $M$ (by definition of bounded operator), and then use the definition of little $o$ notation to show that the terms you want to get rid of are indeed $o(h)$. Nevertheless I realize I too am unable to write up a clean rigorous derivation so would also appreciate if someone could answer.